# Can't run InstallJava executable file

Tags: java, software-installation, jdk

I can't seem to run a Java executable file, even though I've already installed the latest jdk. See the below screenshot.

Am I using the right command, via: `~$ open InstallJava` or is `~$ ./InstallJava` the proper way to run the executable? Thank you! Your help will be very much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, you seem to have not installed java, you need java to run the application you are tying to.

You can either have Oracle java or openjdk, to install oracle java, have a look at this question:

- [How can I install sun oracles proprietary java 6 or 7 jre or jdk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)

or if you want openjdk, you can install it as:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

and then run the application as:

```
./DeepShredder11
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing up the run command. After installing the jdk8 and jre8. I'm not sure if JRE 6 is still available. This might be the problem...